# Why did Virginia turn blue after G.W.Bush?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, parties, political-spectrum, virginia

The historical [map](https://www.270towin.com/historical-presidential-elections/timeline/) of presidential elections shows that Virginia was for decades a red state till 2008, when Obama won this state. Interestingly enough, since then it has always voted for Democrats. What's the reason behind this sudden and dramatic change?

Comment: It should be noted that in 1976, 1992 and 1996 even though Republicans won the electoral votes they did not get over 50% of the votes in the state. https://www.270towin.com/states/Virginia

Comment: "was always" Only seems to go back to 1964. Also with the US election system designed the way it is, it might not really be a dramatic change, even subtle changes (say from 49 to 51%) might result in that observed behavior.

Comment: @Trilarion The civil rights act was passed in 1964 and that lead to members of the Democratic party switching to the Republican party. https://www.history.com/news/how-the-party-of-lincoln-won-over-the-once-democratic-south

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly the Federal Government, centered in Washington DC. Fairfax County, (which sits across the Potomac from DC) for instance [overwhelmingly went Democrat in 2020](https://www.politico.com/2020-election/results/virginia/)

[image]

This one county represents about 20% of the entire state's population. This is Farfax county's trend (Presidential contests, pulled from [here](https://www.fairfaxcounty.gov/elections/returns))

| Year | Republican | Democrat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 202,181 | 196,501 |
| 2004 | 211,980 | 245,671 |
| 2008 | 200,994 | 310,359 |
| 2012 | 206,773 | 315,273 |
| 2016 | 157,710 | 355,133 |
| 2020 | 168,401 | 419,943 |

It's helped Virginia turn bluer, but it's far from a lock. VA has had two Republican governors in that time as well (2009 and 2021).

Comment: But Virginia already turned blue in 2008 (says the question). Was it also Fairfax County in 2008 that overwhelmingly turned Democrat?

Comment: @Trilarion It's trended bluer. [In 2004, 245k voters went for John Kerry](https://www.fairfaxcounty.gov/elections/sites/elections/files/Assets/result/historical/2004_11_NOVEMBER_GENERAL_RESULTS.pdf). In 2008 [310k went for Obama](https://www.fairfaxcounty.gov/elections/sites/elections/files/assets/result/historical/2008_11_november_general_results.pdf). The last Republican to carry the county was [Bush in 2000](https://www.fairfaxcounty.gov/elections/sites/elections/files/assets/result/historical/2000_11_november_general_results.pdf) with 202k.

Comment: The county also must have increased its number of votes/size/population substantially (Biden + Trump=587k) while Bush 202k win means that there likely weren't more than 404k votes in 2000.

Comment: So wrt to the title question "Why did Virginia turn blue after G.W.Bush?" the answer is really suburban D.C. population growth.